# Adding Rows After Missing Sequence

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df) of time series data in long format that has a variable ID and Day and Amount.

```
id  day amount
1   41  15.29
1   42  15.29
1   43  15.29
1   44  15.29
1   45  15.3
1   46  15.3
1   47  15.3
1   48  15.31
1   49  15.31
1   50  15.31
1   52  15.32
1   53  15.32
1   54  15.32
1   55  15.32
1   58  15.33
1   59  15.34
1   60  15.34
1   61  15.34
```

Notice that day 51 is missing. What I want to do is locate the values that are out of missing and then add the row, and renumber then repeat for the entire df.

So it would end up like this:

```
1   41  15.29
1   42  15.29
1   43  15.29
1   44  15.29
1   45  15.3
1   46  15.3
1   47  15.3
1   48  15.31
1   49  15.31
1   50  15.31
-99 51  -99
1   52  15.32
1   53  15.32
1   54  15.32
1   55  15.32
1   58  15.33
1   59  15.34
1   60  15.34
1   61  15.34
```

Comment: For `ID = 2` why there are 2 `-99` in expected output ? There is only one (day = 2) missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `complete` to fill the missing days.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>%
        mutate(DAY1 = DAY) %>%
        complete(ID, DAY, fill = list(DAY1 = -99)) %>%
        select(ID, DAY = DAY1)
df1
#      ID   DAY
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     1     3
# 4     1     4
# 5     2     1
# 6     2   -99
# 7     2     3
# 8     2     4
# 9     3     1
#10     3   -99
#11     3     3
#12     3   -99
```

---

For the updated data we can try to add `day` by group :

```
df1 <- df %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        complete(day = min(day):max(day), fill = list(amount = -99)) 
df1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), DAY = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. I couldn't get that to work so I updated the example. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ScottColwell So what is missing from my answer? `ID` and `amount` column should  -99 ?

Comment: I'm not sure but it isn't adding the row

Comment: Did you assign the output back to new object? I also added another option. Can you check those?

Comment: That got it! Thank you so much for your help. With 47,000 rows I was dreading looking manually.